# Range-Kernel Uncomplementation of Fredholm Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I need to find a normed space $X$ and a compact operator $K:X\to X$ such that $$X\neq N(I-K)\oplus R(I-K).$$ However, all my examples failed so far.

Comment: Haven't thought much of this, but here's my first impression: For a Banach space $X$, we know that $I-K$ is Fredholm of index $0$. It's also known that if $p$ is the ascent of $I-K$, which is finite, then 
$$ 
X= \mathrm{ker}( (I-K)^p ) \oplus  \mathrm{im}( (I-K)^p )
$$
So probably you want to first know the ascent for your examples in hope of finding what you are looking for.